# Import error: No module named 'secrets' - python manage.py not working after pull to Digital Ocean

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I'm following along a course - Django development to deployment.
After pulling it to Digital Ocean everything else ran smoothly. Until 
I tried running python manage.py help

```
(env) djangoadmin@ubuntu-1:~/pyapps/btre_project_4$ python manage.py help
```

and I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 16, in setup
    from django.urls import set_script_prefix
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import (
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .exceptions import NoReverseMatch, Resolver404
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/exceptions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.http import Http404
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.http.request import (
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core import signing
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 45, in <module>
    from django.utils.crypto import constant_time_compare, salted_hmac
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/crypto.py", line 6, in <module>
    import secrets
ImportError: No module named 'secrets'
```

I'm a newbie and have been stuck on this for a while. I just want to know what could possibly cause this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module was added to Python in version 3.6.  Your host is using Python 3.5, hence the secrets module is unavailable. You need a host with Python 3.6+, or a version of Django that doesn't depend on the secrets module

Comment: Just Checked: Python 3.5.2. Which is easier to change host or Django. It sounds like I'd have to make huge changes to the project if I changed Django versions - or am I wrong.

Comment: Yah fixed it - used a host with Python 3.6

Comment: I encounter the same error today with Python 3.9
Anyone has any idea?

Comment: @chocolatte Double check the expected version of Python is running the code, and that you don't have a `secrets.py` in your own code that could be causing problems.  If you are certain that it is being executed by Python 3.6+, open a new question and include the _complete_ error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, solved it by specifying the python version I have installed. i.e

```
$ python3
>>> import secrets
>>> secrets.token_hex(16)
```