# Python: No module named 'secrets' - oracledb module

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-oracledb

I get the following error when running an executable created with PyInstaller. It relates to the module **oracledb**.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "my_script.py", line 1, in
>
> File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495,
> in exec_module   File "oracledb/**init**.py", line 38, in 
> File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in
> exec_module   File "oracledb/connection.py", line 45, in 
> File "src/oracledb/base_impl.pyx", line 47, in init oracledb.base_impl
> **ModuleNotFoundError**: **No module named 'secrets'** [23464] Failed to
> execute script 'my_script' due to unhandled exception!

**Python 3.6**

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61547620/import-error-no-module-named-secrets-python-manage-py-not-working-after-pul) I understand that Python 3.6 is a dependency.

In our environment we have both Python 3.6.8 and Python 2.7

**Build with Python3**

Based on comments from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443088/how-to-change-python-version-for-use-with-pyinstaller), I then tried the following command to build my executable:

```
python3 -m PyInstaller -F my_script.py
```

I still get the same error.

I suspect it has something to do with the 2 versions of Python, but I do not know how to get around it. Does anyone have some advise for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oracledb module uses Cython for its base layer, which means that the modules it imports are not going to be known to PyInstaller. These modules can be found in src/oracledb/*.pyx. You can tell PyInstaller about them, or you can also just copy/paste the imports into a Python module that you include in `my_script.py`. I don't know PyInstaller well enough to be able to tell you how to do the first option, but I'm sure its documentation will get you going!

Comment: Also checkout https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/search?q=pyinstaller&type=issues

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this helped a lot:

Execute pyinstaller so you have a .spec file.
Then edit the spec file with hidden_imports:

```
hiddenimports=['secrets','getpass','ssl','cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2'],
```

Then execute as follows:

```
PyInstaller my_script.spec
```

This gave me an .exe file that works