# python-oracledb error when open exe file which complied by pyinstaller

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

I created python app to fetch data from oracle db and display in table grid
by tkinter and python-oracledb everything work normal when run on vscode
[image: Run with VSCode]

But after I complied into exe file with this command
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Oracle.py

When I open exe file it's showing error like this
[image]

Here is my code
[image]

Why exe file having problem while run through vscode no problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75599583/python-no-module-named-secrets-oracledb-module

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.